# Failed to retrieve object property in WMI (c++)

Tags: c++, events, notifications, wmi

I want to do something with WMI (receiving some event notification) so I start with simple example from MSDN website:

[Receiving Event Notifications Through WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

this program receives an event notification (process creation) through WMI, and calls the function EventSink::Indicate upon receiving the event.

I used the same code in the link above (copy/past) with one change:
in the class EventSink, the function

```
HRESULT EventSink::Indicate(long lObjectCount, IWbemClassObject **apObjArray)
```

I added few lines to retrieve a property of the object (the object is returned in apObjArray):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lObjectCount; i++)
    {
        VARIANT varName;
        hres = apObjArray[i]->Get(_bstr_t(L"Name"),
            0, &varName, 0, 0);
//...
    }
```

now the Get(...) functions returns WBEM_E_NOT_FOUND (The specified property is not found) no matter what I look for (am sure from the documentation that the properties are there...)

please let me know what have I missed ?! any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Name` property is part of the `TargetInstance` object, so you must get the value of the TargetInstance object and then retrieve the value of the `Name` property.

Try this sample

```
HRESULT EventSink::Indicate(long lObjectCount,
    IWbemClassObject **apObjArray)
{
   HRESULT hr = S_OK;
   _variant_t vtProp;

    for (int i = 0; i < lObjectCount; i++)
    {

    hr = apObjArray[i]->Get(_bstr_t(L"TargetInstance"), 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
     if (!FAILED(hr))
     {
       IUnknown* str = vtProp;
       hr = str->QueryInterface( IID_IWbemClassObject, reinterpret_cast< void** >( &apObjArray[i] ) );
       if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
       {
          _variant_t cn;
         hr = apObjArray[i]->Get( L"Name", 0, &cn, NULL, NULL );
          if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
          {
            if ((cn.vt==VT_NULL) || (cn.vt==VT_EMPTY))
             wcout << "Name : " << ((cn.vt==VT_NULL) ? "NULL" : "EMPTY") << endl;
            else
             wcout << "Name : " << cn.bstrVal << endl;
          }
          VariantClear(&cn);


       }
     }
     VariantClear(&vtProp);

    }

    return WBEM_S_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: if I have registered for more than one type of event, do you know how to find out the type in the callback ?

Comment: @RRUZ : Can u help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897897/c-monitor-process-creation-and-termination-in-windows/28921442

Answer (score 0):

The example above seems to have a memory leak.

```
IUnknown* str = vtProp;
```

This assignment uses operator IUnknown* of the _variant_t class, which implicitly calls an AddRef() on the object. So str->Release() needs to be called after usage, since

```
VariantClear(&vtProp);
```

is not enough to decrement the ref count of the object.