# WMI IWbemClassObject::GetNames status complete

Tags: visual-c++, wmi, wmi-service

I make WMI query **SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'**

```
hres = this->m_IWbemServicesComPtr->ExecNotificationQueryAsync(
    _bstr_t("WQL"), 
    _bstr_t(query.c_str()),
    WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS, 
    0, 
    this->m_IWbemObjectStubSinkComPtr.GetInterfacePtr());
```

And always ok before I call method *GetNames* on instance of COM object *IWbemClassObject* (retrieved within my implementation of method *IWbemObjectSink::Indicate*). When I call *IWbemClassObject::GetNames* some WMI mechanism calls my IWbemObjectSink::SetStatus with flag **WBEM_STATUS_COMPLETE** and nothing new events happen!!! I do not call any cancel async methods.

What I do wrong? How to prevent stopping WMI events? How safely call GetNames? After calling *IWbemClassObject::GetNames* I wanna be still subscribed for new events.

**UDPATE:** How I call *GetNames*:

```
HRESULT EnumInstPropNameWMI( IN IWbemClassObject* piappObj, 
                             OUT LPSAFEARRAY* ppsarProp   )
{   
   if (0 == ppsarProp || 0 == piappObj)
      return E_INVALIDARG;       

   HRESULT hres;
   hres = piappObj->GetNames(   0,
                        0,//WBEM_FLAG_ALWAYS | WBEM_FLAG_NONSYSTEM_ONLY,
                        0,
                        ppsarProp);
   return hres;
}
```

**piappObj** is object that was grabbed by way shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12667118/352555)

Comment: The code which you post is incomplete. Can you show how you are calling the `GetNames` function?

Answer (score 1):

This is a dated question, so it may be too late, but trying making the call like this:

```
HRESULT hres;
long unsigned result;

hres = piappObj->GetNames(   
                     WBEM_INFINITE,
                     1,
                     & piappObj,
                     & result);
```